# Unable to capture AxisFault Exception

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client

I have a code which is java wrapper around a web service, on exception it throws an AxisFault exception ( as given below)

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Policy enforcement failed to authenticate the request.
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:446)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at com.tibco.n2.de.services.EntityResolverServiceStub.lookupUser(EntityResolverServiceStub.java:261)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

and the code looks like as given below,

```
try {
                lookupUserResponse = myIntializedObject.lookupUser("someuser", null, null, true);
            } catch (InvalidServiceRequestFault e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InternalServiceFault e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityFault e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                if(lookupUserResponse==null)
                    return false;
            }
```

I also tried replacing all catch block with only single block of Exception e , but still it's not capturing the exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am able to catch AxisFault errors with the following :

```
try {
    ...
} catch (RemoteException ex) {
    if(ex instanceof AxisFault){
        logger.error("Axis Fault error: " + ((AxisFault)ex).getFaultString());
    }
}
```

`AxisFault` is a subclass of `java.rmi.RemoteException`. You can know this by looking at the [API docs](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/AxisFault.html). The class hierarchy is shown in the upper, left-hand corner of the page.

As for why this was not caught when you used `java.lang.Exception` in a `catch` statement, perhaps you could post the relevant code?

Comment: This saved me a lot of time.